# Nav controller back button needs to update table view after core data object is deleted xCode 8.3.1

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data

I've been through all the Q&A that relates to this problem and either the code is too old and/or it won't run or the issue is too simple (i.e the method for sending simple data like a basic string back to a tableview doesn't work with a core data entity)

I have a tableview of records from a core data entity. Selecting a record takes you to a detail view. The user can delete the record from there. However when the navigation controller's back button is pressed and the user is taken back to the tableview, the record still shows in the table.

I know the object has been deleted because going back one screen further and then moving forward to the tableview refreshes it and the object no longer appears in the list of records.

There must be a simple way to get the back button to refresh the tableview? But how?

I'm new to Swift so code examples would be appreciated

Thanks

**********************edit**************************

Here is the code for the RecordView or 2nd view controller

```
@IBAction func Delete(_ sender: UIButton) { // The delete function

    let alertContoller = UIAlertController(title: "Delete?", message: "Are you sure? This can't be undone", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)// This is the alert message
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil) // These are the alert actions

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default) { (action) in //defining the delete action

                 func deleteRecords() -> Void { //The function to delete the record
                    let moc = getContext()
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DestinationsOne") // The fetch request
                    let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    let resultdata = result as! [DestinationsOne] // result as entity

                    for object in resultdata { // Go through the fetched result
                        if object.destID == self.IDTitle{ // If there is a match
                        moc.delete(object) // delete the object
                        }
                    }
                    do {
                        try moc.save() // Save the delete action
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    } catch {

                    }

                }
                func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext { // The get context function
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // The appdelegate as a shared delegate
                    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext // Persistent container is where the objects are stored
                }

                 deleteRecords() // Call the function
```

Then the user hits the back button to return to the TableView called ResultsView.
Though the record in question has been deleted it still shows up in the list of records.

Here's the code from the tableView:

```
class ResultsView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {




@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self // Sets the delegate for the tableview to self
    tableView.dataSource = self // Sets the datasource to self

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DestinationsOne") // The request to retrieve the data from the database
    let context = appDelagate.persistentContainer.viewContext // Persistant container allows the data to be saved by core data


    do {
        try destArray = context.fetch(request) as! [DestinationsOne]} // Putting the data into an array for processing
    catch{
        //error message
    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

var seasonArray = [DestinationsOne]() // The array to hold search results from find by season
var destArray = [DestinationsOne]() // The full data array

let appDelagate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // The appdelegate as a shared delegate

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { // Function copied from UITableView Source
    if seasonArray.count > 0{ // If there are elements in seasonArray
        return seasonArray.count // sets the number of rows to the number of the seasonArray's destination objects
    }else{ // If not
        return destArray.count // sets the number of rows to the number of the destArray's destination objects
    }
}
// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{ // Function copied from UITableView Source

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell // Recycle cells for scrollng

    if seasonArray.count > 0{ // If there are elements  in seasonArray

    cell.Destination.text = seasonArray[indexPath.row].destName //Sets the text in the cell
    if seasonArray[indexPath.row].destImage == nil{ // A check to make sure the image doesn't return nil and cause a crash
        cell.Picture.image = UIImage(named:"Generic.png")!

    }else{ // if not

        cell.Picture.image = UIImage(data: seasonArray[indexPath.row].destImage! as Data) // The table image is either a default image or the image of record
    }

    return cell

    }else{ // If seasonArray is empty
        cell.Destination.text = destArray[indexPath.row].destName //Sets the text in the cell
        if destArray[indexPath.row].destImage == nil{ // A check to make sure the image doesn't return nil and cause a crash
            cell.Picture.image = UIImage(named:"Generic.png")!
        }else{
            cell.Picture.image = UIImage(data: destArray[indexPath.row].destImage! as Data) // The table image is either a default image or the image of record
        }

        return cell


    }
}
```

Comment: There are several ways.  If you show your existing code, people will know which is best in your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. reloadData in the viewWillAppear removes the record but leaves a placeholder behind which, if clicked will crash the app. The solution is to move the code that is in ViewDidLoad into ViewWillAppear as well.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    tableView.delegate = self // Sets the delegate for the tableview to self
    tableView.dataSource = self // Sets the datasource to self

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DestinationsOne") // The request to retrieve the data from the database
    let context = appDelagate.persistentContainer.viewContext // Persistant container allows the data to be saved by core data


    do {
        try destArray = context.fetch(request) as! [DestinationsOne]} // Putting the data into an array for processing
    catch{
        //error message
    }


    tableView.reloadData()

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```